# What is the meaning of "jahileen" or "jahiloon"?

Tags: quran, tafseer, terminology, arabic-translation, uloom-al-quran

What is the meaning of "jahileen" or "jahiloon"? especially in the context of below aaya of Sura Baqarah

وَإِذْ قَالَ مُوسَىٰ لِقَوْمِهِۦٓ إِنَّ ٱللَّهَ يَأْمُرُكُمْ أَن تَذْبَحُوا۟ بَقَرَةًۭ ۖ قَالُوٓا۟ أَتَتَّخِذُنَا هُزُوًۭا ۖ قَالَ أَعُوذُ بِٱللَّهِ أَنْ أَكُونَ مِنَ ٱلْجَـٰهِلِينَ ٦٧

and  also in below aaya of Sura Furqan

وَعِبَادُ ٱلرَّحْمَـٰنِ ٱلَّذِينَ يَمْشُونَ عَلَى ٱلْأَرْضِ هَوْنًۭا وَإِذَا خَاطَبَهُمُ ٱلْجَـٰهِلُونَ قَالُوا۟ سَلَـٰمًۭا ٦٣

**I heard from a genius student  that "jahil" also means emotional while i was thinking that "jahil"means ignorant(having lack of knowledge)**

Answer (score 0):

Jahil (جاهل) is someone who does not obey his own Aql (reason) even if he is Alim (عالم) (knowledgeable). For example, someone knows that smoking is harmful to the body but still does it, so he is knowledgeable (Alim) and at the same time ignorant (Jahil).

The word "Aql" is derived from "عقال" which means "rein." Because Aql controls the good and bad desires.

[Reference](https://hadith.net/post/52103/%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%82-%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%82%D9%84-%D9%88-%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85/)